# Can I update my edmx w/o deleting and adding it again?

Tags: edmx

Is there any alternative ways in updating an `EDMX`?. So far as I notice if I got more than a 100 tables in my edmx and I update one of them in the way of `Delete` and `Adding` it again it causes lag `(not responding)` to my VS. If is there any other way how if not its okay.

Comment: What did you try? Please share. Otherwise there are chances of showing the same method that you tried. I guess, you are trying to update multiple related tables.

Comment: @AT-2016 What do you mean by `what did I try?`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can right click in your EDMX and click "update model from database" [image: 1]

then select the "refresh tab" [image: 2].

Voila !